# Setting IsBusy flag around data object loading

Tags: c#, wpf

We have a relatively large data model class `DataModel`, which is bound to various UI controls.  We want a busy indicator, from WPF Toolkit Extended, to be shown while we are loading an instance of the data model.

Sample code follows.  The busy indicator shows while the `LoadReport` function executes, but disappears after the assign statement, while the binding operations are still processing, i.e. before the interface is "ready".  Is there anything we can do to wait for this?

```
// Show we are busy.
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, (Action)delegate()
{
    this.BusyMessage = "Loading report...";
    this.IsBusy = true;
});

var instance = this.LoadReport();
this.DataModel = instance;

// Show we are no longer busy.
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action)delegate()
{
    this.BusyMessage = null;
    this.IsBusy = false;
});


<toolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding ThisScreen.IsBusy}" BusyContent="{Binding ThisScreen.BusyMessage, TargetNullValue='Please wait...'}" >
    <Grid x:Name="ScreenGrid" />
</toolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

This doesn't seem like an unusual issue, but I didn't have any luck searching for a solution...  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is expected behaviour.

You are setting `BusyMessage` to null and `IsBusy` to false immediately after your `LoadReport()` method has finished. This is giving no time for the rest of the UI to update first.

A better solution might be to raise a `LoadComplete` event and put

```
// Show we are no longer busy.
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action)delegate()
{
    this.BusyMessage = null;
    this.IsBusy = false;
});
```

in the handler for that:

This will give the other bindings time to update - though there's no guarantee that they'll fire first.

Comment: I do understand the cause, but is there no way to know when the Binding processing is completed?

Comment: @dythim - I don't think so, unless you put some code in the `get` of each property so you know when it's been called.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try setting the `BusyMessage` & `IsBusy` inline, rather than invoking with the Dispatcher.

```
this.DataModel = instance;  

// set these directly
this.BusyMessage = null;     
this.IsBusy = false;
```

This should notify the UI that you're no long busy *at the same time* as the DataModel binding occurs - everything will happen at once.

Using the Dispatcher is something like pushing a notification directly into the UI thread. Your busy status becomes 'unlinked' from the other binding and UI changes that you've made.

Comment: That will unfortunately not work for the same reason.  The Binding updates occur in a background thread, not in the inline.

Comment: @dythim I haven't tried it but it's something I would've tried :) The next thing I'd try is probably a hackish `Sleep` before setting `IsBusy` false... but only because I've had this 'slow render' problem myself.  Try using .NET 4.0 - it's very much faster than 3.5 at rendering UI.